# How to learn virtual Reality? What are the fundation courses or resources recommended?

Tags: opencv, image-processing, unity-game-engine, computer-vision, virtual-reality

I am a senior student majoring in CS. I want to learn VR in my master period, but I couldn't find nice resources about VR.

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: Optics & Physics!
Long answer: There are really lots of things that can go wrong with VR.

If you want to find some more "scientific" infos, the real name of VR is "stereoscopy": I've found this page online which seems to be pretty well written.

http://www.sky.com/shop/__PDF/3D/Basic_Principles_of_Stereoscopic_3D_v1.pdf